# Marker moves/disappears on zoom in/out

Tags: android, osmdroid

Following tutorials, my marker shows up in Antarctica (should be over LA). On top of this, it only appears at certain zoom levels. Here's the code I've scratched together:

```
    Drawable myMarker = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
    OverlayItem newItem = new OverlayItem("Here:", "test", new GeoPoint(34,-118));
    newItem.setMarker(myMarker);
    newItem.setMarkerHotspot(OverlayItem.HotspotPlace.CENTER);
    List<OverlayItem> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    newList.add(newItem);
    ItemizedOverlay overlayIcon = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(newList,null, mResourceProxy);
```

Am I doing something wrong? Most, if not all, of the tutorials I've looked at do marker-adding similarly. Why is it failing for me?

Comment: I have too noticed this whilst creating a Google Maps/OSMDroid abstraction layer in my application. I improved the missing marker issue with the code found under my [OpenStreetMapWrapper initialisation function](https://github.com/BrantApps/Polaris/blob/master/library/src/kindle/java/com/brantapps/polaris/osm/OpenStreetMapWrapper.java#L73)

Answer (score 1):

`GeoPoint(34,-118)`, as it has int values, is calling the GeoPoint constructor which assumes values are in micro-degrees.

So this is very very close to (0°,0°). Which should not be in Antartica, but somewhere in the Gulf of Guinea...

Just set values as doubles: `GeoPoint(34.0,-118.0)`, and positionning should be much better.

No idea for zoom levels issue.